# (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am Implementing WepApi Service with Rest but i am unbale to browse the url  it's showing   Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data.Entity.EF5, Version=6.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

IRank.cs `enter code here`

```
 interface Icalculation
{
    collection_master AgentRank(int id);
}
```

Rank.cs

```
enter code here


   public collection_master AgentRank(int id)
    {


        EntityConnection con = new EntityConnection("name=calculationEntities");
        **con.Open();**
        EntityCommand cmd = new EntityCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Agentid,year(Date_Time) as Year,monthname(Date_Time) as Month,SUM(AmountRecevied) as Amount,@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS Rank FROM collection_master join outstanding_master on collection_master.CustomerID =outstanding_master.CustomerID  and  outstanding_master.PhoneNumber='id',(SELECT @rownum := 0) r GROUP BY AgentID,year(Date_Time),monthname(Date_Time) ORDER BY Amount DESC";



        DbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);
        collection_master list = new collection_master();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            collection_master coll = new collection_master();
            coll.CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["CustomerID"]);
            coll.AmountRecevied = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["AmountRecevied"]);
            coll.Date_Time = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["Date_Time"]);
            coll.Area = rdr["Area"].ToString();
            coll.AgentID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["AgentID"]);
            coll.Money_Receipt_No = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Money_Receipt_No"]);
            coll.Payment_Mode = rdr["Payment_Mode"].ToString();
            coll.Money_Receipt_Photo = (byte[])rdr["Money_Receipt_Photo"];


        }
        return list;


    }



enter code here
```

RankController

```
 public class RankController : BaseApiController
{
    static readonly Icalculation obj = new calculation();
    public RankController()
        : base()
    { }

    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "HEAD")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]

    public RankModels  GetRanks(int number)
    {
        collection_master col =  obj.AgentRank(number);

        if (col == null)
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        return TheModelFactory.created(col);

    }
}
```

ApiRouter

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Insertapi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Insert" }


        );


        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "Rankapi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Rank" }


       );




        var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
        xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;

    }
```

Comment: Your variable argument name is `number` in `GetRanks(int number)`. I think it should be `id`. Also It would be great if you post which url you have tried?

Comment: Sounds like the assembly is simply not included in the deployed project. Is the DLL reference marked as `copy`?

Comment: and i am tring uninstall EF6 than it's showing  Version 6.0.2   Unable to uninstall 'EntityFramework 6.0.2' because 'MySql.Data.Entity 6.9.0-alpha1' depends on it